# How to check if an URL refers to a webpage or a file?

Tags: php, file, url

How can I check if a given URL refers to a webpage or a raw file? For now, I check the whole file for containing the string `<html>` but that is neither effective nor reliable.

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
if($content)
{
    // is directory
    if(strrpos($content, "<html>"))
    {
        echo $url . " is a folder." . "<br>";
    }
    else // use raw file...
}
else echo $url . " was not found." . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get the headers and check for the `content-type` header. If it contains `text/html`,  it's a HTML file.

See [Fetch HTTP response header/redirect status with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356640)

This won't be 100% reliable though - in rare cases, it could happen that the server doesn't send a `content-type`header.

Answer (score 0):

Data coming from an URL can be anything, a disk-based file, a data stream generated on-the-fly, database query result, etc. Even the content-type header can be set to anything if the owner of the url is playful or evil (for example setting the content-type to text/html and serving a couple gigabytes of random text).

Beside that, you code is far from the optimal solution, think about a url serving a file having a size of 1 gigabyte of data: your server will suffer.
Better solution to use CURL extension of the PHP: send a HEAD query to the url to discover the properties then download the content to a disk file and examine it later (using mime type detectors or any other solution). Be warning: even using CURL does not protect you from malicious URL's (like mentioned before).