# Checking if a certain URL exists and return an image

Tags: javascript, html, image, url

I need a way to check if an image has been uploaded. I want to do this by checking if a certain URL is existing.

I am getting clients to upload files to my site for their account and I want a tick to appear next to the upload box to show that the file exists.

The uploaded file URLs will be something along the lines of: `http://www.example.com/Practitioner-Area/($user.firstname$)+NI`

The tick file will be:
http://www.example.com/Practitioner-Area/images/complete.jpg

I think I will need a jquery but I have never used them before. So I would prefer a standard html code tbh, but will use jquery if needed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Matt

Comment: Have you tried searching for tutorials on how to upload images?  http://www.matlus.com/html5-file-upload-with-progress/

Comment: your tick file is not accessible you probably need to place it into a public accessible folder (you probably need to fix your htdocs)

Comment: Maybe this can help you;
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926880/using-javascript-to-detect-whether-the-url-exists-before-display-in-iframe][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926880/using-javascript-to-detect-whether-the-url-exists-before-display-in-iframe

Comment: A well-written uploader shouldn't need to access the file and make sure it exists. You ought to be able to bind the "tick" showing event to the success of it uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Try the onerror event:

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="alert('The image could not be loaded.')">
```

Then try to load that outside of screen or something.

Edit: This will create errors on the page so the AJAX result answer is the better one.