# img.onerror() does not appear to fire if URL has a bad domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, webpack

First, let's everybody look at this adorable owl:

```
http://happy.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owl.jpg
```

I'm using that as a test image to see if I can detect, using client-side Javascript, whether a given URL is a legit image. I hunted around online and found some simple code that's supposed to work:

```
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
    console.log("HOORAY! SUCCESS!", img);
}

img.onerror = () => {
    console.log("BOO! FAIL!")
}

img.src = values.image;
```

If I put in a URL which has a valid domain, but bad file path, like this:

```
http://happy.fm/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owlDOESNOTEXIST.jpg
```

...then `onerror()` fires reliably. However, if the *domain* is bogus, like this:

```
http://happy.fmDOESNOTEXIST/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owl.jpg
```

...then `onerror()` never fires. Is this, like, expected behavior? Is there any way around this?

And yes, I realize doing only client-side validation isn't the best way to really handle this issue, but pretend for the moment that this is the only way.

EDIT: it's worth mentioning that I'm seeing this error in a Node.js/Webpack local environment, running on top of the webpack-dev-server. Maybe this becomes some sort of permissions problem.

Comment: That's odd behavior. You could check if the url exists using something like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926880/using-javascript-to-detect-whether-the-url-exists-before-display-in-iframe . Would this suffice for an answer?

Comment: I cant seem to reproduce [the error](https://jsfiddle.net/59bhj75r/), as in, onerror seems to be firing as expected

Comment: If you are doing this in WordPress you can bind `site_url()` at begining and get the images

Comment: @TennysonH: I can't do that, because it requires same domain, and this is cross-domain.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: this is weird. I see that it works on JSFiddle as well. I'm running locally in a Node.js/Webpack environment (localhost:3000). Maybe that's the issue here. I'll see if I can test on a published version of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot. I had an upstream check to validate whether or not the inbound URL was in a valid format. When I checked the domain, I did this:

```
http://happy.f/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owl.jpg
```

It's not legal to have a top-level domain that's a single character, so my validate routine caught that. As soon as I put in a validly-formatted-but-still-bogus top-level domain, like this:

```
http://happy.fasdfasdfasdfasdf/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/random-owl.jpg
```

my `onerror()` method fired.

So...d'oh.