# how to trace 404 from a <use> element in an svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg tag that has `<use>` element inside it.
The use loads an SVG from some path:

```
div.innerHTML = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
<use xlink:href="${href}" href="${href}" /></svg>`
```

(Please note it's a string since it's being used for a customElement shadow template).

What I need is a way to detect a 404 on the `<use>` element in case the href is incorrect.

I tried putting an `onerror="()=>{...}"` attribute, but it's not being called.
Wrapping the with a try/catch block did not help either.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could check if `href` exists with `XMLHttpRequest` before adding it to the svg... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926880/using-javascript-to-detect-whether-the-url-exists-before-display-in-iframe

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I could... I was just hoping to avoid this overhead.

Comment: [Per specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/interact.html#ErrorEvent) you should have an onerror event firing on your `<use>`, it should even bubble up. But no UA has implemented it for `<use>`. Only `<image>` does fire this event and it doesn't bubble up. (Chrome also has it fire on `<svg>` when a script fires an error in a standalone SVG doc.)

Comment: Thanks for this info! So what are my alternatives in that situation? I can't be the only one in need of this, I suppose...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of a better solution than doing an AJAX request (preferably with "HEAD" headers), but that won't tell you if the resource at the other end is really a valid SVG document with an actual element that has an id matching your fragment identifier (`#`). For this you'd also have to parse the result and search for that element (and even maybe check that this element is actually a graphic element?) All in all, nothing trivial I'm afraid.

Comment: Wow... interesting. That sounds like a problem begging to be solved. Well, thank you for the info again!

Comment: That is why we switched from the oldskool ``use``, to a modern Web Component ``<load-svg>`` : https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd